# Batch Naming issue

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am working on a password generator in batch, and after the password is made it saves it as a txt.

My goal was to have multiple files in the folder, all with different tags (example: password01,password02)
I want to be able to generate a variable for the tag, then the name with the tag

(%tag%=01,%name%=password+%tag%.txt)
But I do not know how to. Here is the snippet of code:

```
:md 
md Passwords
tag=<Rand:00:99>
GOTO save

:save
cd Passwords
echo Your Password: !_RndAlphaNum! > %name%.txt
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------
echo Your password was saved
echo ---------------------------
ping 127.0.0.1 > nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------
echo The name is (%name%)
echo ---------------------------
ping 127.0.0.1 > nul
```

I hope this was enough!

Comment: You use _RndAlphaNum as a variable but don't show where it is ever assigned a value   What value is it meant to have?

Comment: use our [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+random+number+in+range) at the top of this page.

Comment: The RNDAlphaNum is the is the password that was generated

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check out the `set` command in Windows. Just execute `set /?` inside a cmd.exe command window to see the help documentation. With this you can learn to set variables as you like.

Your `(%tag%=01,%name%=password+%tag%.txt)` would then become something like `set tag=...` and `set name=password %tag%.txt` for example.

`tag=<Rand:00:99>` is not familiar to me. I think you mean something like `set tag=%RANDOM%` (but this is not very reliable for security purposes! Check out the link Stephan gave you in the comments to learn more about random numbers in batch files).

Further readings that can turn out useful to your plans: `pause /?`, `if /?`, `for /?` and `setlocal /?`, maybe `timeout /?`.